# Android AppCompat, how to remove padding between action bar buttons?

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

In AppCompat, there is a 12dip padding on both sides of the action buttons. I want to make it 0dip. I have read a few posts and tried for hours, no success. Here is the content of my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
     <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/CustomActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton">

    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Ok fixed it. In style11 and style14 (for good measure), I just had to change "actionBarStyle" and "actionButtonStyle" with "android:actionBarStyle" and "android:actionButtonStyle" in the base theme.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Sony Xperia Z3 Tablet Compact android 5.1.1) was the only solution to add:

```
<item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
```

into `CustomActionButtonStyle`

Comment: Thanks. Will give it try as my solution did not work with 5.1